# Check that data are constant within group

Tags: grouping, stata

I often find myself needing to check whether or not variables are constant within a group. This is how I currently go about this (assume that the group is defined by a-b-c and the variable in question is var):

```
bys a b c (var): gen isconstant=var[1]==var[_N]
*manually inspect the results of the below tabulation; if all 1's, then it is constant
tab isconstant
drop isconstant
```

(Note that the above approach assumes that there are no missing observations within a group. I would have to think more about how to approach it if there were missings. And instead of manually checking, could use something along the lines of `assert`.)

This works fine, but is there a more succinct way to do this? Perhaps a one line solution, roughly analogous to `isid ...`, but of course checking for something else.

Comment: Note that `assert` is an alternative.

Comment: Ahhh, good point. `bys a b c (var): assert var[1]==var[_N]`, I believe?

Comment: Correct, but wanting to ignore missings is the killer.

Comment: `bys a b c (var) : assert var == var[1] | missing(var)` should always work for numeric variables, I think.  Strings are sorted the other way, so that missings go first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle behind your approach is also explained in [this FAQ](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/listing-observations-in-group/) but I am not aware of a dedicated command. Still, it is programmable and you are a programmer, so where is yours?

Here is a quick stab:

```
*! 1.0.0 NJC 2 March 2020 
program homog, sortpreserve 
    version 8 
    syntax varname [if] [in] [, MISSing BY(varlist) ] 

    * missings are ignored by default
    if "`missing'" == "" { 
        marksample touse, strok  
        if "`by'" != "" markout `touse' `by', strok 
    }
    else marksample touse, novarlist 

    tempvar OK 
    bysort `touse' `by' (`varlist') : gen byte `OK' = `varlist'[1] == `varlist'[_N] 

    quietly summarize `OK' if `touse' 

    if r(min) == 0 display as err "assertion is false" 
end
```

and some silly examples:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. homog mpg
assertion is false

. homog rep78, by(rep78)

. gen one = 1

. homog one

. replace one = . in L
(1 real change made, 1 to missing)

. homog one

. homog one, missing
assertion is false
```

So, the principles are

1. No news is good news. The only possible output, other than error messages, is a message "assertion is false". This isn't treated as an error. If your taste runs otherwise, clone the program, rename it and change the way it works.
2. `by()` is an option and if specified causes all comparisons to be by the distinct groups of observations so identified.
3. Missings are ignored by default. The option `missing` changes that so that for example 42 and missing are reported as different. This applies also to missing values of any `by()` variables.